# Файлы cookie. Алгоритм обслуживания на современном этапе развития интернета

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, cookie

Я далек от веб-программирования, поэтому решил спросить. Вот раньше вроде файлы cookie были доступны только тому сайту, с которого они получены на твой комп. И другие сайты не могли получить доступ к cookie, которые на твой комп положили не они.

Теперь вроде бы все сайты имеют доступ ко всем cookie. То есть на сайте могут определить, по каким другим сайтам я ходил. Это сделано для того, чтобы контекстная реклама могла более полно учитывать сайты, которые я посещал.

Вопрос:

1. Действительно ли теперь все сайты могут читать все cookie, которые есть у меня на компе и знать какие сайты я посещал?

Comment: Ничего подобного. Cookie по сей день доступны только тому сайту, с которого они получены. Иногда ещё поддоменам, но это только если сайт явно разрешит.

Comment: @andreymal А как же тогда работает контекстная реклама? Захожу я на сайт продажи, к примеру, часов. И после этого во всех рекламных блоках на других сайтах мне предлагают часы. Откуда они знают, что я заходил на сайт продажи часов, если не из cookie?

Comment: Рекламный блок это совершенно отдельный сайт со своими собственными cookie

Comment: На сайте часов стоит какой-нибудь элемент рекламного сайта (как вариант, невидимая однопиксельная картинка), благодаря которому он узнаёт, что вы посетили сайт часов, ну а дальше уже отобразить часы в рекламе не проблема

Comment: @andreymal То есть система обмена рекламой работает через свои cookie? Но все равно, по своим cookie они могут понять, что я ходил на сайт продажи часов. Получается, если сайт участвует в системе обмена рекламой, то всегда можно узнать, кто и когда был на этом сайте.